# Which one and why: (alphabets and integers sets) OR (alphabets set and integers set)?

Tags: academic-writing, grammar

Consider the two phrases:

1. alphabets and integers sets
2. alphabets set and integers set

Are both grammatically correct? If so, which one is a better style and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression is that both are wrong and that what you want to say is "*alphabet and integer sets*".

### Why "Alphabet and Integer Sets"...

A set of alphabets, aka "*alphabet sets*", is a container of alphabets. It's a grouping, or collection, that holds only alphabets and can contain any number of alphabet sets including zero and approaching infinity.

Logically, it would look something like this:

[image]

And the integer set would look like:

[image]

### However...

If you mean to pluralize the alphabets and integers, then you're probably looking at something like this:

- A set of alphabet sets
- A set of integer sets

Answer (score 0):

The use of "alphabets" is a bit odd. You likely mean "letters" [A, B, C...], unless you literally mean sets of alphabets, as in [Latin, Cyrillic...].

Then you're distinguishing between:
letter sets and integer sets [a,b,c] and [1,2,3]
OR
letter and integer sets [a,1,b,2,c,3]

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as a mathematician, if you mean a set of some, but not all integers, I would say "a subset of the Integers". If however, you mean the set of all the integers, then say "the set of Integers".